# Change User name in Windows 10 by Editing Registry

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-registry, username

I tried to changed my User name in Windows 10 buy making registry edits. I am having some problems and I want to see if there are some other edits that I need to make the rectify these problems.

I changed the User name in my Account Profiles. Then I went into my reg edit and replaced all occurrences of "John Doe" with "John_Doe". in the relevant folders

So I now have two User folders in C:\Users

John Doe; and Joen_Doe

The folder for John Doe only has a "Desktop" item in it. The folder for John_Doe appear to have all my relevant folders.

However when using the John_Doe account, I periodically get access/permission errors on certain folders. I have been getting this message when I start VSCode:

"Setup was unable to create directory: C:\Uder\John Doe\App Data Error 5 Access was denied"

Also when I ma in the John_Doe account I cannot access: My Music My Photos My Videos

I get this error: C:\User\Documents\My Music is not accessible

If I right click on those folders and go to security and then click advanced I see the following under Group or user names:

Everyone SYSTEM John_Doe(DESKTOP-OQ8FQ5\John_Doe) John Doe (johndoe@gmail.com) >>Microsoft account Administrator (DESKTOP-OQ8FQ5\Admminstrator

I am wondering if by chance I missed an edit in my reg edit. And/or I need to delete the remaining John Doe User folder with the Desktop item.

Lastly, I know I can simply create a new user account and transfer all file to it But I currently cannot access all the files due the pointes noted above in (My Music, My Photos, My Videos.

Comment: Make sure the change is worth the effort.  Windows makes the user name unique so I dropped my efforts here as there was not (to me) a need to change the user name.

Comment: One can make Windows completely unusable with such a Registry change. The safest thing might be to salvage all you can, wipe the disk, reinstall Windows and restore data and apps.

Comment: Do the following, unassociated the account with a Microsoft Account, choose your username, then associate the account with a Microsoft Account. Since your desired profile name is likely taken, you might have to do it once, delete the profile directory that’s unused then repeat the process.